# Basic program, Interesting output? Explanation

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning about pointers, and I'm running this program from the tutorial that gives some interesting output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int var = 20; /*actual variable declaration */
    int *ip; /*pointer variable declaration*/

    ip = &var; /*store addres of var in ip variable*/

    printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var);

    /*address stored in ip variable*/
    printf("Address of stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip);
    /*access the value using pointer */
    printf("value of *ip variable: %x\n", *ip);

    return 0;

}
```

And to my understanding, the site says my output should be Two matching memory locations, and the value of 20 for the "Value of *ip variable" part. I have no issue with the memory locations, they both come up as the same just as one would assume however, the last part, its telling me the value of the *ip variable is 14?

```
Address of var variable: 6d73b8cc
Address of stored in ip variable: 6d73b8cc
value of *ip variable: 14
```

Whats going on here? Compiled with gcc, which gives one warning about format %x expects an unsigned integer but argument 2 has type of....

```
MorePointers.c:10:9: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var);
         ^
MorePointers.c:13:9: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address of stored in ip variable: %x\n", ip);
```

Correct me, please, if I am wrong, but could it be due to the format, which when expecting an unsigned integer could cause the number to be one other than 20? being an unsigned integer is within values 0 to 65,535 or 0 to 4,294,967,295, while an integer is within values -32,768 to 32,767 or -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is that you've printed the integer value `20` as a hexadecimal value, which rightly is displayed as `14`.  I suspect you were expecting `20` decimal. :)

Comment: I only expected the decimal version, as thasts what the tutorials same code, outputted, that being said, your answer makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5):

Some fixes :-

```
printf("Address of var variable: %x\n", &var);
```

This is incorrect, a pointer should be printed as a pointer value

```
printf("Address of var variable: %p\n", &var); /* << ensure pointer value */
```

When you call `printf`, it mixes fixed text with parameters in order...

```
printf( "hello %d world %d today %d\n", 1,2,3 );
```

Prints hello 1 world 2 today 3

The way a parameter is displayed is based on the format specifier.

```
%s /* displays as a string */
%d /* displays as an integer in normal decimal */
%x /* displays an integer in hexa-decimal. */
%f /* displays as a floating point */
%p /* displays a pointer address */

Decimal goes      0,1,2,..,8,9,10,11,...,14,15,16,17,...,20
Hexadecimal goes  0,1,2,..,8,9, A, B,..., E, F,10,11,...,14
```

Comment: Thank you for the fixes, while they werent my code and from the tutorial, still very helpful info, cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the hexadecimal value of `var` or `*ip`, which is `0x14`.

Use `%d` for decimal value.

Answer (score 2):

The first two `printf()` statements have undefined behaviour, as `%x` requires the corresponding parameter to be of type unsigned, not a pointer.  Hence the warnings.   Look up the `%p` format if you want to print the value of pointers (and convert the pointers to `(void *)` to use that).

`%x` prints the value in hex, base 16.   The value of `20` (decimal) in hex is `14`  (`1*16 + 4`).  Strictly speaking, you should convert an `int` to `unsigned` to use `%x`.

Answer (score 1):

printing addresses with printf() should be done with '%p' not '%x'.

If you compiled with all the warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) 
then the compiler would have told you, for line 10 and line 13:

```
warning: format: '%x' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument two has type 'int*' [-Wformat=]`
```

The last call to printf() is passing a type of 'int' but the '%x' is expecting a unsigned int.

suggest declaring 'ip' and 'var' as `unsigned int` rather than `int`

or change the last printf() to:

```
printf("value of *ip variable: %d\n", *ip);
```

you can read.learn about the format specifiers for printf() at:

```
<http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output>
```

or reading the `printf` man page

Comment: Thank you for the compiler flags!